# Problem when using full join but not using left join. Why?

Tags: mysql

When I use a `left join` on different databases, it works but not when I use `inner join`. Why ?

```
SELECT tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.*, tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.*
FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent
FULL JOIN tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking ON tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.idEmailTracking = tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.idEmailTracking
```

> Unknown table 'tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent'

But when using

```
SELECT tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.*, tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.*
FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent
LEFT JOIN tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking ON tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.idEmailTracking =
tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.idEmailTracking
```

I have not this error message, but I can only have the results of the left table. Or, I wish all the results like an full join.

Answer (score 0):

Full join don't exists in mysql  but you can produce the same result using both left join and right join in UNION

```
SELECT tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.*
      , tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.*
FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent
LEFT JOIN tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking  
  ON tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.idEmailTracking = tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.idEmailTracking
UNION 
SELECT tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.*
      , tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.*
FROM tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent
RIGHT JOIN tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking  
  ON tkblue_tklabel_dev_archdata.EmailTracking.idEmailTracking = tkblue_tklabel_dev_data.EmailContent.idEmailTracking
```